# Where can I find Greek and Hebrew plain text sources?

Tags: greek, hebrew, tools-of-biblical-studies

**Source texts are available with software**

There are numerous Biblical source texts available (free, in "public domain") for download into Bible software type programs.

**Where else are they available? (in a plain text file type)**

I am looking for either 1) source files or 2) recommended method(s) for generating source files.

**Purpose**
I want to pair up custom Hebrew-Greek Interlinears for study (while away from the computer) in the original languages. I would like to make these to be of publishable quality. My desired interlinear is nowhere available for purchase. The answer to this question would be related to [my question on the TeX SE site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106417/how-to-set-up-tex-software-to-begin-making-existing-greek-and-hebrew-texts-into), but this question here deals only with source availability.

**Texts I'm Looking for:**
(Must have reliable single manuscript type sources or reliably-edited sources)

- Hebrew Bible (Old Testament)
- Hebrew New Testament (i.e., Delitzsch's translation)
- Greek Old Testament (i.e., Rahlf's Septuagint (LXX))
- Greek New Testament (i.e., Textus Receptus, or a UBS edition)

*An answer might include a linked site for downloadable text files, or a recommended brand software export feature (with a view to one or several of the texts I'm looking for). Once an answer has a source, we can comment/edit the rest of the sources so far as they may be found.*

Comment: Hiya. Just wanted to let you know that I voted to close this question, not because it's bad but because it's off-topic. However, if you ever wanted to come into [The Library](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1505/the-library) I'd love to chat about this. I've found some great projects and we can nerd out like crazy talking about texts.

Comment: I wasn't able to yet create a tag for "source texts", but I would have tagged this question, primarily under that label. There are a few university projects dedicated to keeping the electronic text, and all the "critical" editions of texts today are using electronic sources and software - not to mention efforts to advance distribution and translation.

Comment: I don't debate the value of electronic texts - I've got my own ideas for them. I'm just saying that I don't think that this is the place for this question.

Comment: Establishing the (source) text is always a primary step in Exegesis, which is integral to Hermeneutics. The textual basis is always an implicit part of doing Biblical Studies. If the Nestle-Aland text differs from both the UBS4 and the Textus Receptus, there are textual reasons (manuscript evidence) for it. Therefore, the textual study is a part of understanding the translation and theological issues that have branched from it. Good texts are Gold (even digital). For some purposes, such as combining texts into new Polyglots for study, digital texts make possible what used to take a lifetime.

Comment: No doubt I agree with everything you've said. I really do. I've my Master's in New Testament and am particularly keen on Greek grammar, Source and Textual Criticism. Your question is certainly germane to the *field* but not necessarily to the *site.* As I said before, join us in [The Library](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1505/the-library) which is a more appropriate location for such a conversation :)

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics, Qoheleth-Tech!  I'm sorry we have to close this question and it doesn't reflect poorly on you in any way.  It's marginally off-topic in the sense that it isn't really asking about the texts or about a specific hermeneutical approach, but is rather asking where to find resources.  I picked the "Not Constructive" reason since it doesn't really fit with the way Stack Exchange functions.  I see you've gotten involved in chat, which is really the best place to discuss this.  I look forward to seeing you around and reading your future answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**These are Some Source Texts Available in Plain Text**

- *Westminster Leningrad Codex Hebrew Text*. Go to this [site](http://www.tanach.us/Tanach.xml#Technical) and see "Zipped Archives of Tanach Books". Click your desired text to download the zipped text files with accents and vowels, or just vowels without accents.
- *Rahlf's LXX*. Go to this [site](http://www.chinesetheology.com/Bible&Theology/LXXGreekOT.htm) and click "zipped file of LXX text. This downloads a .doc file. Open it in Word, and then save a copy as Unicode (UTF-8) and your done. Be aware that the file is very large in your word processor, be patient in doing this!
- *SBL Greek New Testament*. Go to this [site](http://sblgnt.com/download/) and see the "Plaintext" link to download. See also the [end user license](http://sblgnt.com/license).
- *Hebrew New Testament* - will edit this answer when I find it For now, see it at this [site](http://patrologia.narod.ru/biblia/index.htm). Click on the Hebrew for "Berit Hadshah" (or here: [Delitzsch](http://patrologia.narod.ru/biblia/hnt/delitzsh/index.htm)).

*Note: if you text doesn't display correctly, you'll need unicode Hebrew and Greek fonts in your system. You can get them from sil.org. Likely, you'll have them already.*

Comment: there's also the unbound bible project at biola. i've combined the sblgnt with james tauber's parsing and have a postgresql database and am currently working with a SQL Server database too.

Comment: Ahh, swasheck, I would be interested in your process for sblgnt/tauber/sql. That might not be par for this site, but many of our professors in Biblical Studies would value the sources for doing this stuff (in my opinion of their interests!).

Comment: Hey, does the unbound Bible have full text output for download? I had not seen it there when I was searching this answer. Thanks - and maybe we'll catch up on your project sometime...

Comment: I don't understand your question. http://unbound.biola.edu/index.cfm?method=downloads.showDownloadMain

Comment: Jackpot, I didn't even see the select Box...great!

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom of [this page](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/), it states,

> Seven free offline resources for learning Torah:
>
> Our MTR DOS-based program for the PC including Mishneh Torah, Bible,
> Targum Onqelos, Mishnah, Tosefta, Yerushalmi, and Bavli in Hebrew with
> its own search engine with Hebrew interface (or optional English
> interface)
>
> Our individual HTML Bibles in ZIP files in either Hebrew
> with cantillation marks, Hebrew with vowels only, Hebrew without
> vowels - masoretic spelling, Hebrew without vowels - full spelling, or
> verse-by-verse parallel Hebrew and English, or English only  Our HTML
> Mishneh Torah alone in a ZIP in Hebrew or our Mishneh
>
> Torah with links to a complete included Hebrew Bible in a larger ZIP in Hebrew
>
> Our HTML version of the four major authoritative sources of the Oral Law (Mishnah, Tosefta, Yerushalmi, and Bavli) in a single ZIP in Hebrew
>
> Our Bibles and Mishneh Torah for the Pocket PC
>
> Our Bibles in either Hebrew or English and Mishneh Torah in Hebrew for the Palm Pilot
>
> Our Torah 101 encyclopedia of basic information about Torah observance, Jewish practices, holidays, people, and beliefs in a single ZIP in English

Would any of those be of any use to you?

Comment: I have emailed that site to see if they can help me locate it on their site. This is close. But two things: html has too much markup, also I need the vowel pointing (I see now they have a file with it). BTW, I like those audio files on mechon-mamre.org.

Comment: I've not searched for such files before. I wish I could be of more help.